# Make common login between joomla and moodle?

Tags: joomla2.5, moodle

I am new in joomla and moodle customization. please help me in how to make common login between joomla and moodle both plate form?

Answer (score 2):

You could use the Single Sign On features in Moodle(OpenID or LDAP) or a custom module like Joomdle.

http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/living/education-a-culture/lms/10021

Answer (score 0):

You could also try JFusion which provides sso for Joomla + many other php applications.